# Fatal error in in Joomla site

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am click the add-to-cart button some error is shown

Site is developed joomla & virtue mart

Fatal error: Call to undefined method vmJsApi::js() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/car/templates/theme402/html/com_virtuemart/cart/default.php on line 22

Comment: vmJsApi::js ('facebox');

Answer (score 1):

vmJsApi::js ('facebox')

This loads the facebox.css, testing if the file exists in the template (in templates/MY_TEMPLATE/css folder) or if negative, loads it from the virtuemart css (components/virtuemart/assets/css folder).

so the method is calling but no function exists, try commenting it out and refreshing the page.

hopefully this answers your question.

https://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/virtuemart/wiki/JavascriptCSS_Template_Overrides_and_Avoiding_Conflicts_between_Libraries